# Why is my app not starting on iOS and just showing a loading screen?

Tags: ios, codenameone, loading

I have developed an app in Codename One. In the simulator the app is working on both iPhones and Android phones. Now I installed the app on my phone. It's working perfectly on different Android phones. Then I installed it on an iPhone. I can install it, but then I try to start the app and a loading screen appears and it's just loading, nothing else happens.

I didin't change the `init(Object)` method much. I just added
`if (Display.getInstance().canForceOrientation()) {
            Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
}`.

In the `start()` method I create an object of the Login class for an OAuth2 Login and then I add the necessary data (Oauth2 URL, Redirect URI, Client ID, Client Secret) to the object. Then I call the `doLogin()` method. I wrapped my code in a try/catch(), but it doesn't change anything.

```
try {
            Login login = new Login() {
                @Override
                public boolean isNativeLoginSupported() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                protected boolean validateToken(String token) {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            login.setOauth2URL(URL_LOGIN);
            login.setRedirectURI(URL_REDIRECT);
            login.setClientId(CLIENTID);
            login.setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
            login.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
                @Override
                public void loginSuccessful() {
                    WelcomeForm.getInstance().show();
                }

                @Override
                public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
                }
            });
            login.doLogin();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(t);
            Form error = new Form("Errror", new BorderLayout());
            TextArea txt = new TextArea(t.toString());
            error.add(CENTER, txt);
            error.show();
        }
```

Comment: something went wrong, I guess, how did you debug your app so far? what did you see?

Comment: What do you do in your `init(Object)` and `start()` methods? Do you show a `Dialog` in one of them? If so that can be a problem

Comment: @holex I didn't debug the app yet, I will debug it today, because I don't have a Mac

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I don't show a dialog in one of the methods.

Comment: I'm guessing your oauth code triggered an exception on iOS. I suggest commenting out code until you can narrow down the source of the exception.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog The problem is the oauth code. I tried starting the app without this code and it works perfectly. So isn't it possible to have oauth code in an iOS app? Is there another way to do the login?

Answer (score 0):

Try making this change to your code, it might be triggering invoke and block somewhere in the process, this should workaround that:

```
Form loading = new Form("Login");
Button login = new Button("Login");
login.addActionListener(e ->
    try {
        Login login = new Login() {
            @Override
            public boolean isNativeLoginSupported() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean validateToken(String token) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        login.setOauth2URL(URL_LOGIN);
        login.setRedirectURI(URL_REDIRECT);
        login.setClientId(CLIENTID);
        login.setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        login.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void loginSuccessful() {
                WelcomeForm.getInstance().show();
            }

            @Override
            public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            }
        });
        login.doLogin();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e(t);
        Form error = new Form("Errror", new BorderLayout());
        TextArea txt = new TextArea(t.toString());
        error.add(CENTER, txt);
        error.show();
    }});
loading.show();
```

Original answer below:

There is no inherent limit that should prevent OAuth on iOS. I'm guessing you are getting an exception which triggers an error `Dialog` and causes this failure. I suggest wrapping the area with a try/catch() and logging the error as a `Form` or `Log` e.g.:

```
try {
   // your OAuth code
} catch(Throwable t) {
   Log.e(t);
   Form error = new Form("Errror", new BorderLayout());
   TextArea txt = new TextArea(t.toString());
   error.add(CENTER, txt);
   error.show();
}
```

Once you know the exception and error message you can try narrowing the issue further. If you have access to the log we can also see the stack trace e.g. via `Log.sendLogAsync()`.

Comment: I wrapped my code with a try/catch(), but nothing else happens. It doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the same thing is happening, except that the form with the loading sign has a title (loading).

Comment: I looked again at the code and I see that the `Login` class invokes the `Oauth2` class which inside shows a `Dialog`. That's problematic on launch and might not even work in a `callSerially`. Try the newly suggested workaround. Once the button is active the UI is fully initialized and dialogs should function correctly. If this works we'll try to think of a better workaround.

Comment: The form with the button appears, but after clicking the button the loading screen appears and it's just loading and nothing else happens.

Comment: I'm guessing this is failing because of the bad decision in the component to put the browser component within a `Dialog`. This code was never reached in our tests as on iOS OAuth usually goes to native login which you explicitly disabled. I think we'll need to fix this. You can file an issue create your own OAuth logic based on that code which uses a Form instead of a Dialog. It should actually be much simpler than the current code which was designed for a much older version of Codename One.

Comment: This specific block is the problem: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/eb681d212f7a89438c53223460f433c72316c6a5/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Oauth2.java#L164-L184